# Java applet permission denied, security exception

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I started learning Java a few weeks ago and now I am in the process of creating a japplet game.

I am using Mac os x and whenever I try to run the applet in the browser I get the following exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied:
```

How can I fix this so the JApplet would run? The files are all on local and I'm running the JApplet locally in the browser.

The following the is html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Java Game!</title>
</head>
<body>

    <applet code="/local/path/to/MainApplet.class"
            width=500
            height=500>
    </applet>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

The following is the full console output:

```
Java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied:
 file:/path/to/MainApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Applet2ClassLoader.java:209)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:201)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:678)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied: file:/path/to/MainApplet.class
```

**UPDATE #2**

I tried the same code in Windows and there was no problem at all. It's only on Mac that's giving this exception, any ideas?

Comment: What was the bit that came after `Permission denied:`?  The answer to your question might be "don't do that", or maybe "only do that in a signed & trusted applet".  It is impossible to say which, until you reveal what 'that' is.

Comment: *"I started learning Java a few weeks ago and now I am in the process of creating a japplet game."*  As an aside, coding applets is not a good way to learn Java GUI programming.  They are significantly more tricky to develop & deploy than (for example) a `JFrame` launched from a link using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @AndrewThompson the course requires that my app be deployed as an applet, don't have a choice unfortunately :( I've also updated the Q.

Comment: 1) Don't forget to add the homework tag for homework questions.  2) Slap your teacher for being so stupid as to force people into applet development. 3) It is time to drop the `path/to` in your descriptions.  State explicit/exact paths.  If 'anonymizing' path is intended to provide security, change the project set-up so that the paths are anonymous to start with.  4) For ease of development, ensure the class is in the same directory as the HTML, or if the class is in a package, a sub-directory. 5) This security problem is most likely indicating the applet is just incorrectly set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Since the applets are components that are provided from the Internet, the security framework of Java requieres that you must sign the applet if it will access to locar resources like write or read from hard disk.

For sign the applet you can check the following link: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html

Comment: Is it possible for the applet to run without signing anything? I'm at the start of development and having to bundle it into a jar and signing it every time is too much... also the applet won't be released to the public, just for grading purposes

Comment: @zentenk - that only applies if you're using the local filesystem - are you actually using the local filesystem in the applet, or is it complaining that it can't access MainApplet.class in the first place? It sounds like the latter.  If the class is under local, and the html is in local, try a relative path.  I.e. put the html file in path/to/local,  and refer to MainApplet.class (with no path)

Comment: @James Yes it is using the local filesystem. When I refer to it with a relative path I get an error saying it cannot find the class file. I've also set permissions to 777 and I still get the same result.

Comment: @If you are learning Java and don't want to sign the applet JAR, maybe you don't need to use a Applet you can use a JFrame or a Frame for run your program.

Comment: @ErnestoCampohermoso course requires the program to be an Applet, no way around that...

Comment: In that case you need to sign the applet. You can use ANT for automate the process.